# Conditional statement combining case_when and mutate

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want create a bivariate map plotting two variables: `production` and `possession`. In order to give part of the data the correct colour I want to add a column with color codes `"A", "B", "C"` for one variable and for the other `1, 2, 3`. Then later concatinating the two. Just so that the data is coded like the following example:

[image]

Here's my example df and failing code:

```
library(dplyr)

example_df <- structure(list(production = c(0.74, 1.34, 2.5), possession = c(5, 
23.8, 124.89)), .Names = c("production", "possession"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

example_df %>%
  mutate(colour_class_nr = case_when(.$production %in% 0.068:0.608 ~ "1",
                                     .$production %in% 0.609:1.502 ~ "2",
                                     .$production %in% 1.503:3.061 ~ "3",
                                     TRUE ~ "none"),
         colour_class_letter = case_when(.$possession %in% 0.276:9.6 ~ "A",
                                         .$possession %in% 9.7:52 ~ "B",
                                         .$possession %in% 52.1:155.3 ~ "C",
                                         TRUE ~ "none"))
```

With these results...:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  production possession colour_class_nr colour_class_letter
       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>              
1      0.740       5.00 4               none               
2      1.34       23.8  4               none               
3      2.50      125    4               none
```

But this IS the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  production possession colour_class_nr colour_class_letter
       <dbl>      <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>              
1      0.740       5.00 2                A               
2      1.34       23.8  2                B               
3      2.50      125    3                C
```

I'm new with `case_when()` incombination with mutate, hope someone can help.

Comment: your `%in%` statement is looking odd.  `0.628:0.608` creates `0.628`. These are numeric why don't you use numeric comparisons like `<` and other? Probably that already solves your problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
example_df %>%
  mutate(colour_class_nr = case_when(production < 0.608 ~ "1",
                                     production > 0.609 & production < 1.502 ~ "2",
                                     production > 1.503 ~ "3",
                                     TRUE ~ "none"),
         colour_class_letter = case_when(possession < 9.6 ~ "A",
                                         possession > 9.6 & possession < 52 ~ "B",
                                         possession > 52 ~ "C",
                                         TRUE ~ "none"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  production possession colour_class_nr colour_class_letter
       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>           <chr>              
1      0.740       5.00 2               A                  
2      1.34       23.8  2               B                  
3      2.50      125    3               C
```

The only difference is the use of `>`and `<`, although some of the conditions don't make a whole lot of sense in your example. You also don't need the `.$` in the latest versions of dplyr.